# Attach max from group to every row of results ?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

I have similar to the following database structure:
ApplicationService table :

```
+-----+--------------+----------+---------------+
|  id | name         | status   | application_id
|  1  | Service 1    |  1       |     24
|  2  | Service 2    |  2       |     24
|  3  | Service 3    |  3       |     25
+-----+--------------+----------+----------------
```

And there is other table with status definitions:
CustomerStatus

```
+------------+--------------+----------+-----------+
|  status_id | name         | level    | is_closed
|  1         | Status 1     |  2       |     1
|  2         | Status 2     |  1       |     0
|  3         | Status 3     |  3       |     1     
+------------+--------------+----------+----------
```

The status for each row of the ApplicationServices is calculated as the max level status within the records grouped by application_id.

So to get all records from ApplicationServices with statuses would result in something like this:

```
+-----+--------------+----------+----------------+-------------+-----------
|  id | name         | status   | application_id | status_name | is_closed
|  1  | Service 1    |  1       |     24         |  Status 1   |    1
|  2  | Service 2    |  2       |     24         |  Status 1   |    1
|  3  | Service 3    |  3       |     25         |  Status 3   |    1
+-----+--------------+----------+----------------+-------------+-----------
```

Is there an efficient way to attach the results with max(level) grouped by application_id to every row of the result set ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT A.id, A.name, A.status, A.application_id, CS.name AS status_name, CS.is_closed
FROM ApplicationService A
INNER JOIN (SELECT AA.application_id, MAX(CS.level) AS maxLevel
            FROM ApplicationService AA
            INNER JOIN CustomerStatus CS ON AA.status = CS.status_id
            GROUP BY AA.application_id
          ) AS AA ON A.application_id = AA.application_id 
INNER JOIN CustomerStatus CS ON AA.maxLevel = CS.level;
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need and is actually almost twice as fast as what I had before. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[See working SQLfiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e6fc1/6).

You will probably have to perform a sub-query. The subquery would simply be joining the two tables together, grouping/collapsing by `application_id` and then fetching the maximum `is_closed` value:

```
SELECT
     t1.status AS `status`,
     t1.application_id AS `app_id`,
     MAX(t2.is_closed) AS `max_is_closed`
   FROM applicationstatus AS t1
  LEFT JOIN customerstatus AS t2 ON
    t1.status = t2.status_id
  GROUP BY t1.application_id
```

The max `is_closed` value should then be accessible by the `max_is_closed` alias when you incorporate the subquery:

```
SELECT
  t1.id AS id,
  t1.name AS name,
  t1.status AS `status`,
  t1.application_id AS application_id,
  t2.name AS status_name,
  t3.max_is_closed
FROM applicationstatus AS t1
LEFT JOIN customerstatus AS t2 ON
  t1.status = t2.status_id
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT
     t1.status AS `status`,
     t1.application_id AS `app_id`,
     MAX(t2.is_closed) AS `max_is_closed`
   FROM applicationstatus AS t1
  LEFT JOIN customerstatus AS t2 ON
    t1.status = t2.status_id
  GROUP BY t1.application_id) AS t3 ON
  t1.application_id = t3.app_id
```

The output from the query:

[image]